# How does ConnectionMultiplexer deal with disconnects?

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

The [Basic Usage](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/master/Docs/Basics.md) documentation for StackExchange.Redis explains that the `ConnectionMultiplexer` is long-lived and is expected to be reused.

But what about when the connection to the server is broken? Does `ConnectionMultiplexer` automatically reconnect, or is it necessary to write code as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25946747/983064) (quoting that answer):

```
if (RedisConnection == null || !RedisConnection.IsConnected) {
  RedisConnection = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(...);
}
RedisCacheDb = RedisConnection.GetDatabase();
```

Is the above code something good to handle recovery from disconnects, or would it actually result in multiple `ConnectionMultiplexer` instances? Along the same lines, how should the `IsConnected` property be interpreted?

*[Aside: I believe the above code is a pretty bad form of lazy initialization, particularly in multithreaded environments - see [Jon Skeet's article on Singletons](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/singleton.aspx)].*

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Here is the [pattern recommended by the Azure Redis Cache team](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cache-dotnet-how-to-use-azure-redis-cache/#connect-to-the-cache):

```
private static Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer> lazyConnection = new Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer>(() => {
    return ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("mycache.redis.cache.windows.net,abortConnect=false,ssl=true,password=...");
});

public static ConnectionMultiplexer Connection {
    get {
        return lazyConnection.Value;
    }
}
```

A few important points:

- It uses Lazy<T> to handle thread-safe initialization
- It sets "abortConnect=false", which means if the initial connect attempt fails, the ConnectionMultiplexer will silently retry in the background rather than throw an exception.
- It does **not** check the IsConnected property, since ConnectionMultiplexer will automatically retry in the background if the connection is dropped.

Comment: Do you have a reference for the recommendation? I did find their MVC movie app example, but it would be helpful to have more background from the source. Here's what I found: http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/06/05/mvc-movie-app-with-azure-redis-cache-in-15-minutes/

Comment: It seems that this would be the place to go: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn690521.aspx

Comment: Current link seems to be https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cache-dotnet-how-to-use-azure-redis-cache/#connect-to-the-cache

Comment: So is this pattern proper-way ?

Comment: Old post but do you not need the isThreadSafe parameter set to true?  as in:       
        public Lazy(Func<T> valueFactory, bool isThreadSafe);

Comment: looks like in my case it is not retrying. can someone check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65261761/problem-in-lazy-connection-logic-in-stackexchenage-redis

Comment: @MX313 I know it's been a year, but in case anyone else comes this way:  Lazy(Func<T>) by default assumes isThreadSafe = true and LazyThreadSafetyMode = ExecutionAndPublication.  You should only need to use a constructor defining one of those if the instance initialized is *not* thread safe or should *not* allow ExecutionAndPublication.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.lazy-1.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_Lazy_1__ctor_System_Func__0__

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need that type of verification in order to fix broken connections. Some thread safety should also be factored in as well. This is how I usually do this:

```
private static ConnectionMultiplexer _redis;
private static readonly Object _multiplexerLock = new Object();

private void ConnectRedis()
{
    try
    {
        _redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("...<connection string here>...");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //exception handling goes here
    }
}


private ConnectionMultiplexer RedisMultiplexer
{
    get
    {
        lock (_multiplexerLock)
        {
            if (_redis == null || !_redis.IsConnected)
            {
                ConnectRedis();
            }
            return _redis;
        }
    }
}
```

Then I use the `RedisMultiplexer` property everywhere I need to call the Redis endpoint. I don't usually store the result of the `GetDatabase()` call because the documentation says it's a pretty lightweight call.

Comment: A big problem with this approach is that connections will be leaked until the ConnectionMultiplexer instances are cleaned up the CLR garbage collector.  If the cache is under heavy load it's possible to hit the 10k connection limit.  There's also no good way to call Dispose() on the old ConnectionMultiplexer, since another thread could still be trying to use it.  The best approach we have found is to ignore the IsConnected property and let ConnectionMultiplexer retry the connection on its own.

Comment: @MikeHarder I had this suspicion, which is why I asked the question. Thanks for confirming and clarifying.