# Fault tolerant Aerospike connection in a Web service

Tags: c#, multithreading, aerospike

I need to make persistance connection to Aerospike noSQL DB in a Web service.

In a not-Web application, connection is straightfoward as

```
using (AerospikeClient client = new AerospikeClient("127.0.0.1", 3000)) 
{
...
}
```

But in a Web service application, creating new client for each request is expensive.  The Best Practices say this too: "use only one client instance per cluster in a program and share that instance among multiple threads. AerospikeClient and AsyncClient are thread-safe."

I can make a static object, but what if the client disconnects, either by error or timeout (24 hours max connection living time)? Can anyone provide any fault-tolerant code spippet? (Maybe similar to redis pattern [How does ConnectionMultiplexer deal with disconnects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28792196/how-does-connectionmultiplexer-deal-with-disconnects))

Answer (score 3):

The client manages a socket pool. If a socket error or timeout occurs, the socket is disposed of.

Comment: So, is it safe to merely write 'public static AsyncClient client = new AsyncClient(policy, host, port);' and use it 24/7?

Comment: Thanks. I also should add failIfNotConnected = false to the policy, otherwise I risk to get TypeInitializationException.