# Redis Out of Memory Exceptions, but still have plenty of memory

Tags: redis, .net-core, stackexchange.redis, amazon-elasticache

I'm using the [StackeExchange.Redis](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis) project to interact with Redis in our .NET Core C# project.

Under heavy load, our Redis connections will begin to fail with the following exception:

```
StackExchange.Redis.RedisServerException: OOM command not allowed when used memory > 'maxmemory'
```

The problem is that we have a ridiculous amount of free memory left. We're using Elasticache, so it's easy to lookup:

[image]

We can also connect to Elasticache through a shell, and see that there is memory avaialable, and interact with it just fine.

This is the code I used as a layer over the Connection information.

```
    public class RedisTimeConnectionManager : IRedisConnectionManager
{
    // More info about the Lazy<> pattern https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28792196/how-does-connectionmultiplexer-deal-with-disconnects
    // Additional information about the multiplexer: https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/master/docs/Basics.md
    private static Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer> RedisConnectionMultiplexer = new Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer>(() =>
    {
        return ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(ConnectionString);
    });

    private static string ConnectionString { get; set; }

    public RedisTimeConnectionManager(string connectionString)
    {
        ConnectionString = connectionString;
    }

    public ConnectionMultiplexer GetConnectionMultiplexer()
    {
        return RedisConnectionMultiplexer.Value;
    }

    public IDatabase GetDatabaseConnection()
    {
        return RedisConnectionMultiplexer.Value.GetDatabase();
    }
}
```

I then pass this Connection layer to my redis "time" manager. This is the code that is throwing the OOM error:

```
public class TimeRedisManager : ITimeRedisManager
{
    private IRedisConnectionManager RedisConnectionManager { get; }

    public TimeRedisManager(IRedisConnectionManager redisConnectionManager)
    {
        RedisConnectionManager = redisConnectionManager;
    }

    public async Task<RedisUserTimelineGetValueDto> GetValueAsync(string id)
    {
        string key = $"time:{id}";

        HashEntry[] entries = await RedisConnectionManager.GetDatabaseConnection().HashGetAllAsync(key);

        // Parse and return values...
    }
}
```

Because Elasticache has over 7.5GB free of memory, and because I can interact with it through a shell, I'm assuming it's either the StackExchange.Redis library, or an issue with connection management in my code.

.NET CORE 2.1 
StackExchange.Redis v 2.0.513

**One last important thing** - when this exception happens, it keeps happening. Restarting the services that interact with Redis does nothing. Only restarting the Elasticache nodes solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redis could take 2 times the memory required by data stored in it.

Read more here : https://redis.io/topics/admin

> If you are using Redis in a very write-heavy application, while saving
>   an RDB file on disk or rewriting the AOF log Redis may use up to 2
>   times the memory normally used. The additional memory used is
>   proportional to the number of memory pages modified by writes during
>   the saving process, so it is often proportional to the number of keys
>   (or aggregate types items) touched during this time. Make sure to size
>   your memory accordingly.

So, if the data stored in Redis takes 8 Gb of space, under heavy load Redis may consume 16 Gbs. You may have to tune the memory accordingly if that's the case.

Comment: This seems like the correct answer. The Elasticache instance is a write heavy instance, and after looking at our Cloud metrics, the crashing starts to happen after very heavy write-loads, and after the free-able RAM starts to exponentially dip.

Comment: So whats the solution?