# How to save redis data on disk from ram

Tags: redis, ram, disk

I am using redis as session server . All data stored in ram . To store in disk 
from RAM I use BGSAVE command in cli its stop all services .

Comment: What was your question please?

Comment: What is the process to get backup of redis database

Comment: You already said you use `BGSAVE`.

Comment: That's not working ,  when i use BGSAVE its stop redis server due to huge data.

Answer (score 1):

> If you are using Redis in a very write-heavy application, while saving an RDB file on disk or rewriting the AOF log Redis may use up to 2 times the memory normally used. The additional memory used is proportional to the number of memory pages modified by writes during the saving process, so it is often proportional to the number of keys (or aggregate types items) touched during this time. Make sure to size your memory accordingly.
>   https://redis.io/topics/admin

You may need to tune the memory accordingly if this is the case.
[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52993019/redis-out-of-memory-exceptions-but-still-have-plenty-of-memory/52998436#52998436)