# Redis consuming more memory overtime for same number of keys

Tags: redis, spring-data, spring-data-redis

Background:

My service caches data in redis standalone setup in prod environment, using spring-data-redis `RedisTemplate` using `@Cacheable` annotation. I cache data for 3 mins , however I saw that my redis memory was gradually increasing (this observation was done for 1-2 weeks). I suspected that my redis keys were not getting evicted, as number of keys constantly increased (this could be due to constant load too). So I disconnected my service from redis for 3 min and observed redis memory . All the keys got expired and memory usage dropped.

However, when I restarted my service to cache data in redis , within 1-2 mins of doing the same I got the same number of keys as before( this was expected as load was high on my service) but the memory usage of redis was significantly less.

Below is a graph of number of keys in redis before, during redis not being used and after reconnecting my service to cache

[image]

Below is the graph of memory used by redis for above scenarios

[image]

As you can see , for the same number of keys , redis is consuming very high memory when it was run for a long duration (1-2 weeks). When I disconnected my service from redis to empty all keys and then again restarted to use redis cache , my memory usage was very low, for same number of keys

What could explain this behaviour? Could it be memory leak , for connection I have a class which extends `CachingConfigurerSupport`. The connection bean and redis template bean are as follows:

```
@Bean
public JedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory() {
    JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnFactory = new JedisConnectionFactory();
    jedisConnFactory.setUsePool(true);
    jedisConnFactory.setHostName(redisMasterUrl);
    return jedisConnFactory;

}

@Bean
public RedisTemplate<Object, Object> redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory cf) {
    RedisTemplate<Object, Object> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<Object, Object>();
    redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(cf);
    return redisTemplate;
}
```

Anything I am missing out pertaining to connections , do I need to close connections anywhere when using `RedisTemplate`?

Comment: Are you using persistance in Redis ? If so,  Redis could take 2 times the memory required by data stored in it. See more here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52993019/redis-out-of-memory-exceptions-but-still-have-plenty-of-memory/52998436#52998436

Comment: @rainhacker redis persistence is off i cross checked

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is that once peak memory usage is reached by Redis , it never frees it until restarted.This is the nature of the memory allocator it uses.

Reference:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/redis-db/ibhYDLT_n68