# unable to connect with azure redis cache after deployment to server

Tags: c#, azure, stackexchange.redis

UnableToConnect on some-prod.redis.cache.windows.net:6380/Interactive, Initializing/NotStarted, last: NONE, origin: BeginConnectAsync, outstanding: 0, last-read: 5s ago, last-write: 5s ago, keep-alive: 60s, state: Connecting, mgr: 10 of 10 available, last-heartbeat: never, global: 5s ago, v: 2.1.58.34321
I'm trying to create connection like it

private static Lazy azureRedisCacheConnection = new Lazy(() =>
{
return ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(AzureRedisCacheConfiguration.Instance.ConnectionString);
});

```
    public static ConnectionMultiplexer RedisCacheConnection
    {
        get
        {
            return azureRedisCacheConnection.Value;
        }
    }
```

```
[RedisConnectionException: UnableToConnect on some-prod.redis.cache.windows.net:6380/Interactive, Initializing/NotStarted, last: NONE, origin: BeginConnectAsync, outstanding: 0, last-read: 5s ago, last-write: 5s ago, keep-alive: 60s, state: Connecting, mgr: 10 of 10 available, last-heartbeat: never, global: 5s ago, v: 2.1.58.34321]

[RedisConnectionException: No connection is active/available to service this operation: EVAL; UnableToConnect on Some.redis.cache.windows.net:6380/Interactive, Initializing/NotStarted, last: NONE, origin: BeginConnectAsync, outstanding: 0, last-read: 5s ago, last-write: 5s ago, keep-alive: 60s, state: Connecting, mgr: 10 of 10 available, last-heartbeat: never, global: 5s ago, v: 2.1.58.34321, mc: 1/1/0, mgr: 10 of 10 available, clientName: INNOWIN134106, IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=8,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=1,Free=32766,Min=8,Max=32767), v: 2.1.58.34321]
   StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.ExecuteSyncImpl(Message message, ResultProcessor`1 processor, ServerEndPoint server) +394
   StackExchange.Redis.RedisBase.ExecuteSync(Message message, ResultProcessor`1 processor, ServerEndPoint server) +166
   StackExchange.Redis.RedisDatabase.ScriptEvaluate(String script, RedisKey[] keys, RedisValue[] values, CommandFlags flags) +190
   Microsoft.Web.Redis.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<Eval>b__0() in C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\59b31e8e4035fd30\src\Shared\StackExchangeClientConnection.cs:68
   Microsoft.Web.Redis.StackExchangeClientConnection.OperationExecutor(Func`1 redisOperation) in C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\59b31e8e4035fd30\src\Shared\StackExchangeClientConnection.cs:86
   Microsoft.Web.Redis.StackExchangeClientConnection.RetryLogic(Func`1 redisOperation) in C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\59b31e8e4035fd30\src\Shared\StackExchangeClientConnection.cs:122
   Microsoft.Web.Redis.StackExchangeClientConnection.Eval(String script, String[] keyArgs, Object[] valueArgs) in C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\59b31e8e4035fd30\src\Shared\StackExchangeClientConnection.cs:68
   Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisConnectionWrapper.Set(ISessionStateItemCollection data, Int32 sessionTimeout) in C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\59b31e8e4035fd30\src\RedisSessionStateProvider\RedisConnectionWrapper.cs:137
   Microsoft.Web.Redis.<SetAndReleaseItemExclusiveAsync>d__25.MoveNext() in C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\59b31e8e4035fd30\src\RedisSessionStateProvider\RedisSessionStateProvider.cs:433
   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +68
   Microsoft.AspNet.SessionState.<ReleaseStateAsyncImpl>d__80.MoveNext() +809
   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +31
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +68
   Microsoft.AspNet.SessionState.TaskAsyncHelper.EndTask(IAsyncResult ar) +58
   System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +510
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +213
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +172
```

Comment: locally its working

Comment: What Azure service you are deploying your app into?

Comment: KrishnenduGhosh-MSFT  simply I'm just .net mvc app deploy to some machine

Comment: can you please start your post with some code that shows how you are trying to connect and not only the error message? that is not very helpful. Also info like: are you using SSL? is your server forcing SSL-only?

Comment: KrishnenduGhosh-MSFT redis.cache.windows.net:6380,password=XXXXXXXY=,ssl=True,abortConnect=False"

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe the connectionStrings should append `,allowAdmin=true`. That is just my guess.

General, you should add rules in Firewall.

[image]

**TroubleShooting.**

You can delpoy your webapp with debug model, and you can use remote debug to catch the error.

You can [download my sample code in github](https://github.com/Jason446620/redis-mvc-core-master). My sample code is tested, you can try it.

For more details, you can read my answer in another post.

[How to reconnect redis client after redis server reboot/scale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63696226/how-to-reconnect-redis-client-after-redis-server-reboot-scale/63702525#63702525)