# C# - The best way to create Redis connection pools?

Tags: c#-4.0, connection-pooling, stackexchange.redis, azure-redis-cache

In order to improve application performance, thought of trying & creating the redis connection pool to share the load, instead of rotating single same redis connection to cater all the incoming requests, as the per the suggestion by Redis team [here](https://gist.github.com/JonCole/925630df72be1351b21440625ff2671f#general-guidance)

What would be the best way of creating StackExchange.Redis connection pool for same Redis server config using C# & keep rotating one connection after another from the pool to cater the incoming request?

Is there any SDK/nuget package available to create Redis connection pool?

At present we are reuse the single ConnectionMultiplexer created using Lazy pattern via singleton class which will initiate single redis connection object on the very first request & will be reused throughout the application lifetime.

P.S: thread safe can be ignored as all the instance in the connection pool using same Redis server config.

Comment: Pls click links in my answer  [How to reconnect redis client after redis server reboot/scale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63696226/how-to-reconnect-redis-client-after-redis-server-reboot-scale/63702525#63702525)  , I think they are useful to you.

Comment: Thanks @JasonPan, my query not about redis reconnect if server reboots. I am looking for best way to create Redis connection pool using lazy pattern using C#

Answer (score 0):

There's a library that I have implemented two years ago exactly for that requirement. It's thread safe and it creates the connection pool lazily.
Also, you can use built in implementations of connection selection strategy such as round-robin and load based.
The NuGet is https://www.nuget.org/packages/StackExchange.Redis.MultiplexerPool/
You can see sample here https://github.com/mataness/StackExchange.Redis.MultiplexerPool/blob/master/samples/RedisConnectionPoolConsoleApp/Program.cs